# Send list from Python to Prolog PySwip

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, prolog, swi-prolog

I`m writing a program on Python and Prolog, using the library PySwip. I need to send list from Python to Prolog. i did it like this:

```
from pyswip import Prolog
p = Prolog()
p.assertz("fruits([apple,banana,orange])")  # Create list
p.assertz("result(X) :- fruits(L), member(X, L)")  # Rule for checking if an element in a list
print(list(p.query("result(orange).")))  # Return True if element in list
```

But i need to make list a separate object, because execute some actions before question. Help me how to send object in Prolog

```
from pyswip import Prolog
p = Prolog()
fruits = [apple,banana,orange]
p.assertz("How send to list fruits ???") # I dont know how to write this request
```

Thank you everyone for advance

Comment: I don't know `Prolog` and `PySwip` and I don't know if I understand  problem but it looks like normal string so you could convert to string using `"fruit( {} )".format(fruits)` or using `f-string` like `f"fruit( {fruit} )"`

Comment: but problem can be that in Python it would have to be list of strings `fruits = ["apple","banana","orange"]` and it would create string `fruits(['apple', 'banana', 'orange'])` with `' '` and if this makes problem then it would need `",".join()` to create string `apple,banana,orange` without `' '` - and then use with `"fruit( {} )"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know `Prolog` and `PySwip` and I don't know if I understand problem but it looks like normal string so you could convert to string using `"fruit( {} )".format(fruits)` or using f-string `f"fruit( {fruit} )"`

```
from pyswip import Prolog

p = Prolog()

fruits = ['apple','banana','orange']

text = f"fruits({fruits})"
print(text)

p.assertz(text)
p.assertz("result(X) :- fruits(L), member(X, L)")

print(list(p.query("result(orange).")))
```

But in Python it has to be list with strings.

And it will create string `fruits(['apple', 'banana', 'orange'])` with items in quotes `' '`  .

I don't know if quotes makes some problem but if you need without quotes

```
fruits = ['apple','banana','orange']

text = ','.join(fruits)     # apple,banana,orange

text = f"fruits([{text}])"  # fruits([apple,banana,orange])

print(text)
```

Comment: yes, its really working. Thank you.